# Which pools offer payouts via generation? (Eligius-style payouts)

Tags: mining-pools, pool-payout-methods, eligius

As the title says, which pools offer payouts to miners directly in the generation transaction of the block, as in Eligius?

Comment: P2Pool for one thing, but that's not strictly speaking a pool...

Comment: How isn't it a pool?  It's a group of people pooling their hashing power and sharing rewards.  That makes it a pool as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Luke recently posted](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=18313.msg944736#msg944736) that:

> Fresh-mined coins for payouts were innovated by pools in the following
>   order: puddinpop, Eligius, BitPenny, p2pool.

Comment: If puddinpop, Eligius, and BitPenny pay their miners via the generation transaction, does P2Pool have any advantage over them, security-wise? It would seem all these pools are equally immune to potential pool manager fraud, then.

Comment: @Geremia: I think I answered my own question: non-P2Pool pool managers still have complete control over the payout queue, viz., who to include in the next block's generation transaction and how much to pay them. So, P2Pool is more secure against pool manager fraud, even than Eligius et al.